# Distorted circle in android using canvas

Tags: android, canvas, bitmap, geometry

```
Paint p = new Paint();
    p.setAntiAlias(true);
    p.setColor(Color.DKGRAY);
    int y=getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getWidth();
    Config conf = Bitmap.Config.RGB_565;
    Bitmap bmp =Bitmap.createBitmap(y,y,conf);
    Canvas c = new Canvas(bmp);
    c.drawCircle(y/2 ,y/2, y/3, p);
    iv.setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable(bmp));
```

By this code i do get circle ,which is looking as:-
[image]

Now the problem is that it doesnt look like a true circle ,and it looks like an oval shape..

So what should i do ??

Thanks in advance,....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
iv.setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable(bmp));
```

use [setImageBitmap()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#setImageBitmap%28android.graphics.Bitmap%29), instead of `setBackgroundDrawable()`, and `setScaleType()` to `FIT_CENTER`

Comment: --If i want to do the animation of this circles what should I do ??

Comment: chek the Android Animation Framework. It is really simple to use.

Comment: also, since it is another question you should open a new OP